# How can I open a new tab in Chrome with Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, python-3.x

Yes a similar question has been asked. Yes I read it, yes I know about `webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)` and no this is not what I am searching for.

I've been trying to find a way to open a new tab "in background".
An equivalent of *right-click --> Open Url in a new tab*.
So I can stay on my tab while my script open its tab.

Is this doable?

Comment: how do you run Python in Chrome?

Comment: Is it 100% essential that the tab opens in the background?

Comment: Not runing Python in Chrome, the script will control chrome.

Comment: Indeed. I'll be working reading my tab while my script prepare the next one ...

Comment: Will the tabs stack up without me noticing ?